# Take the start date of a data frame

Tags: r

With this we can create a data frame with days having the start day:

```
  dataframe = seq(as.Date("2000-09-01"), by="days", length=11)
```

If we have already a dataframe which has values can we do the same?

Comment: What dataframe do you have? And what do you want to do with dates in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That actually creates a `Date` vector, not a data frame.

```
x <- seq(as.Date("2000-09-01"), by="days", length=11)
class(x)
# [1] "Date"
```

If you define the starting date as the earliest date (i.e., the minimum date), then use `min`:

```
min(x)
# [1] "2000-09-01"
```

But if you're looking for the first element in the vector (which is also the earliest in your case, but of course it doesn't have to be), then grab it by its index:

```
x[1]
# [1] "2000-09-01"
```